# Twilio - delayed job, cron job, or worker or what?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, delayed-job

I am building an app that is using Twilio and we need to call Twilio's server a certain period after the call starts.

I'm using RoR and right now its on Heroku, but we can move it elsewhere if need be.

I've looked at Delayed Jobs and Cron jobs but I don't know enough about it to know which route I should take.

Seems like Delayed jobs and cron jobs are usually reoccurring (not very accurate with timing) and are started with rake not by a user action, right?

What tool will give me minute accuracy for this use case?

Comment: You can use deplayed_job and the hooks it provides to do this

Comment: The job worker is either a rake task or by calling "Delayed::Worker.new(:queues => ENV['QUEUE'].to_s.split(',')).start" at the end of your boot sequence (or simply "Delayed::Worker.new.start" if you don't have any QUEUE to load)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Evangelist here.

I like to approach this with [Redis](http://redis.io/) backed worker queues. Redis is a key-value store, which we can use with [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) (pronounced 'rescue'), and [Resque-Scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler) to provide a queueing mechanism. For example, we can have the application respond to user interaction by creating a call using the [Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon). Then we can queue a worker task that will do something with the call a specified amount of time later. Here, I'm just going to get the status of the call after a few seconds (instead of waiting for the [status callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#asynchronous?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) when the call completes).

Heroku have a really good walkthrough on using [Resque](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque), there is also an excellent [Rails Casts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque?view=asciicast) on Resque with Rails. A [data add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/#data-stores) is available from Heroku called [Reddis Cloud](https://addons.heroku.com/rediscloud) to provide a Redis server. Although for development I run a local server on my computer.

I've created a simple app based on the Heroku tutorial and the Rails Casts episode. It has a single controller and a single model. I'm using a [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) on the model to create an outbound Twilio call. Such that when a new `Call` record is created, we initiate the outbound Twilio call:

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Twilio functionality is in a concern...
  include TwilioDialable

  after_create do |call|
    call.call_sid = initiate_outbound call.to, 
                                      call.from,
                                      "http://example.com/controller/action"
    call.save
    call
  end 
end
```

I'm using a concern to initiate the call, as I may want to do that from many different places in my app:

```
module TwilioDialable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  include Twilio::REST
  def initiate_outbound to, from, url 
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV['TW_SID'], ENV['TW_TOKEN']
    client.account.calls.create(to: to, from: from, url: url).sid
  end 
end
```

This simply creates the outbound Twilio call, and returns the call SID so I can update my model.

Now that the call has been placed, so I want to check on its status. But as we want the call to ring a little first, we'll check it in 15 seconds. In my controller I use the `Resque.enqueue_in` method from Resque-Scheduler to manage the timing for me:

```
Resque.enqueue_in(15.seconds, MessageWorker, :call => @call.id)
```

This is instructing Resque to wait 15 seconds before performing the task. It is expecting to call a Resque worker class called `MessageWorker`, and will pass a hash with the parameters: `{:call => @call.id}`. To make sure this happens on time, I set the `RESQUE_SCHEDULER_INTERVAL` to 0.1 seconds, so it will be very precise. The `MessageWorker` itself is fairly simple, it finds the call record and uses the Call SID to get the updated status and save this to the database:

```
class MessageWorker
  @queue = :message_queue
  def self.perform params
    # Get the call ID to do some work with...
    call = Call.find(params["call"])
    # Setup a Twilio Client Helper with credentials form the Environment...
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV['TW_SID'], ENV['TW_TOKEN']

    # We could get some 
    status = client.account.calls.get(call.call_sid).status
    # Update my call object.
    call.status = status
  end 
end
```

When I ran this locally, I had to start the Redis server, the Redis Worker rake task, the Redis Schedule rake task, and I am using Foreman and Unicorn to run the Rails app. You can configure all of this into your Procfile for running on Heroku. The [tutorial on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque) is a great walkthrough for setting this up.

But now I can create a call and have it dial out to a phone. In the mean time I can refresh the `calls/show/:id` page and see the value magically updated when the worker process is run 15 seconds later.

I also find that [`resque-web`](https://github.com/resque/resque-web) is really useful for debugging Resque, as it makes it really easy to see what is happening with your tasks.

Hope this helps!